# Copy List of objects into List in another object

Tags: c#, forms, list, object, collections

I have been trying to figure this out in c#. I just started doing C# so I would appreciate your help.

I want to copy a list of Objects to a list in another object.

It looks something like this.

```
class Person
    {
        public String fName;
        public String lName;
        public List<House> housesOwned = new List<House>();
        public Student(String FName, String LName)
        {
            this.fName = FName;
            this.lName = LName;

        }
    }

class House
    {
        public String Address;

        public House (String ad1){
            this.Address1 = ad1;

        }
    }
```

Now, in my Form I created a list of objects type House (it has 2 objects of type House to be precise), which are the two houses that the person owns.

Something like : `List<House> housesList = new List<House>;`

Basically what I am trying to do is to copy the `List<House> housesList` created in the form to the `List<House> housesOwned` which is the list in the object Person. This will happen when pressing the submit button. So far I got this:

```
List<Person> person = new List<Person>(); // declared at the beginning of the form
.....
private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            person.Add(new Person(personName.Text, personLName.Text));
            //I do not know what comes next to copy the list housesList to the list housesOwned
            MessageBox.Show("Done!");
        }
```

I want the objects houses to be copied containing their addresses. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Why you have in `Person` class constructor with name `Student`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the instance of the new Person you created, then add the `houseList` to that instance.

```
private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var newPerson = new Person(personName.Text, personLName.Text);
        newPerson.housesOwned.AddRange(houseList);
        person.Add(newPerson);
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
}
```

Comment: hey! Thank you! this worked! I never thought of creating the instance to then add the list! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Yeh sure! Thanks! See is there any way to create a method like get; set; for the list in the class Person?

Comment: Sure you can, In C# they're called [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - There are many examples on properties on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    var person = new Person(personName.Text, personLName.Text);

    person.housesOwned.AddRange(housesList);

    people.Add(person);
```

Comment: I tried it and says that Person does not have defined any housesOwned or any extension method. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user1102815 i actually meant the person object not the list of persons .. will modify my answer.

Comment: hey! Thank you! I got it to work! Should I add any access method in the class Person for this list as well? Is it possible to do something like get set for a list? Thanks!!!

Comment: The list is already accessible. and yes you can add get/set if you want. And please accept @Blachshma answer since that helped you.